# VPN connection (iPhone)?

Tags: http, proxy, header, vpn

I want to start a VPN Connection between my iphone and a VPN server.
I know that i can do that bye set VPN settings in iphone.
But i want to do that programmatically from the iphone.
So, how to setup a VPN connection in code(Objective c)?

Comment: This blog post can walk you through. [Configure and manage VPN connections programmatically in iOS 8](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot do it. At least not officially...

see [iPhone VPN connect app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564263/iphone-vpn-connect-app)

However, you may be able to point your app to through an existing VPN channel if it already exists. I would recommend creation of instructions for the user on how to create the VPN connection.